# Cannot import twice the same collection to Azure DevOps Services

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-migration

I am trying to migrate my Azure DevOps Server on-premise to the Azure DevOps Services.

I have to remove all our process customizations, and we will lose some info, so I would like to migrate our collection with our customizations and then make another import without these customizations.

The problem is that when I try to import the second time, it make me remove the first organization:

```
+ [Error] VS403256: Organization 'first-organization' should be deleted prior to starting this import.
```

Is there a way to import twice the same collection to Azure DevOps Services?

Comment: It's telling you the problem and the resolution. No, you can't re-import. You have to delete the existing organization.

Comment: But why can i not import one collection and then other with a different name? Does Azure know in someway that is the same collection? That is the question...

Comment: An on-prem collection is exactly equivalent to an organization. One organization can't have more than one collection.